# append function (list) inside for-loop: changes to dictionary do not take effect

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, append

I have a list of dictionaries. I want to create a list that contains each dictionary multiple times (according to their quantity).
However, each dictionary shall have a new key-value pair with an id number.

If tried to do it like this.

```
list1 = [{'name':'item A', 'qty':'3'}, {'name':'item B', 'qty':'5'} ]
new_list_of_dicts = []

for item in list1:

    qty = int(item['qty'])

    for i in range(1,qty+1):
        item['id'] = i
        print(item)
        new_list_of_dicts.append(item)

print (new_list_of_dicts)
```

However, even though the dictionaries in the for loop (item) contain the right id in every iteration. Just one version of the dictionary is added to the new list (highes id).
How can I fix this in order to have increasing numbers in the new list?

The individual dictionaries look like this:

```
{'name': 'item A', 'qty': '3', 'id': 1}
{'name': 'item A', 'qty': '3', 'id': 2}
{'name': 'item A', 'qty': '3', 'id': 3}
{'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 1}
{'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 2}
{'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 3}
{'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 4}
{'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 5}
```

A dataframe created out of the list shows the same id for each part

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(new_list_of_dicts)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
     name qty  id
0  item A   3   3
1  item A   3   3
2  item A   3   3
3  item B   5   5
4  item B   5   5
5  item B   5   5
6  item B   5   5
7  item B   5   5
```

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'item' is not defined`.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: I've extended the code. Now the example is reproducible. Sorry, it wasn't in the first place.

Comment: Because *you keep adding the same dictionary on each iteration of the inner loop* `new_list_of_dicts.append(item)`

Comment: It's not the same dictionary. The value of ['id'] is changed in ever iteration. As you can see in the individual dictionary, these changes take effect.

Comment: I append the dictionary in every iteration and also change the value of ['id'] in every iteration. That's why I expect the results to have different values for ['id']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the `id` of the **SAME** dictionary object in the loop. So it changes **all** versions of it. In order to have different dictionaries, you need to copy it using `.copy()` (or `deepcopy()` if your dictionary has dictionary values) as a new object and use that to append:

```
list1 = [{'name':'item A', 'qty':'3'}, {'name':'item B', 'qty':'5'} ]
new_list_of_dicts = []
for item in list1:

    qty = int(item['qty'])

    for i in range(1,qty+1):
        #this creates a copy so when you change the id, it only changes the id of this object and not the original item you added.
        item = item.copy()
        item['id'] = i
        new_list_of_dicts.append(item)

print (new_list_of_dicts)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'item A', 'qty': '3', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'item A', 'qty': '3', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'item A', 'qty': '3', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'item B', 'qty': '5', 'id': 5}]
```